# uploading application to itunes connect - ERROR 90098

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bluetooth-lowenergy

This morning i tried to upload my application to itunes store to review it.

I used the Application Loader from Apple to do this job  but, after few minutes, the process failed with this error during the uploading:

**ERROR ITMS-90098: This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'bluetooth-le' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value '9.0'**

I put the key bluetooth-le in the application .plist to force the installation only on the compatible devices. (because the ios app will communicate trought BTLE with a specific device.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would open a support case with Apple and/or log a bug

Comment: Ok. For someone who's interested i solved the problem using a dictionary value in the .plist instead of an array. In this case specifying the key 'bluetooth-le' with value set to 'true' everything works fine.

Comment: You should add an answer to your own question; others may have the same problem

Comment: You're right dude. Thanks however for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who's interested i solved the problem using a `dictionary` value in the .plist instead of an `array`.

In this case specifying the key `'bluetooth-le'` with value set to `'true'` 
everything works fine.

Old .plist

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>bluetooth-le</string>
</array>
```

New .plist

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<dict>
    <key>armv7</key>
    <true/>
    <key>bluetooth-le</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```